# malloc() and assign: C code in run well in OS X; not in Win 8.1

Tags: c, windows, macos, malloc

The code I wrote worked without any problem in OS X, but I got the following error when I ran it on VS 2013 community.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x001A3D22 in Myproject.exe: 0xC0000005:
Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
```

Here is the code with problem. The original code has some more lines, but the code below generates the same error by itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int **p;
    p = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * 5000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        p[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5000 * 25);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5000 * 25; i++) p[0][i] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5000; i++) p[i][0] = 0;      //<- error on this line

    printf("donw!\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the status when error occured. i and p are colored as red.

```
    name        value                         type
    i           4118                          int
    p           0x00758fe8 {0x0075de48 {0}}   int * *
    p[0]        0x0075de48 {0}                int *
    p[0][i]     0                             int
    p[i]        0x00000000 {???}              int *
```

Can anyone tell me what makes this kine of difference between OSX and Windows? In OSX I compiled the code with gcc.

Comment: Have you checked the return values from `malloc()`?  You're allocating a lot of memory — around 2.5 GiB if my calculation is correct.  Is it possible to determine how much memory you can use on Windows?  Are you compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit (on each platform; the default on Mac will be 64-bit unless you did something to choose 32-bit compilation).

Comment: Your program allocate a lot of memory. If you run out of available space malloc will return 0. It is your responsibility to verify that. This is not a difference between OSX and windows but rather a matter of available memory.

Answer (score 2):

When `p[i]` is `NULL`, it is most likely the result of `malloc` failing to allocate the needed memory. Add checks to detect that.

```
p = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * 5000);
if ( p == NULL )
{
   // Deal with error.
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
{
   p[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5000 * 25);
   if ( p[i] == NULL )
   {
      // Deal with error
   }
}
```